# AVPlayer show cached data

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, uislider, avplayer

How to show cached data in UISlider from AVPlayer? I play audio with AVPlayer from network, and i want to show downloaded data.

Comment: I have something working, look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691854/avplayer-streaming-progress/7730708#7730708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment - there is a way to get time ranges from an avplayer that shows how much data is downloaded from a remote URL.

[AVPlayer streaming progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691854/avplayer-streaming-progress/7730708#7730708)

Answer (score 0):

You should observe the property loadedTimeRanges for your player`s currentItem.
like this:

```
guard let currentItem = self.player?.currentItem else {return}
currentItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

then realize the function:

```
observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)  {
    guard object is AVPlayerItem else {return}
    let item = object as! AVPlayerItem
    if keyPath == "loadedTimeRanges" {
        let array = item.loadedTimeRanges
        guard let timeRange = array.first?.CMTimeRangeValue else {return}
        let totalBuffer = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.start) + CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.duration)
        tmpTime = CGFloat(tmpTime)
        print("totalBuffer - \(totalBuffer)")
        let tmpProgress = tmpTime / playDuration
        progressCallBack?(tmpProgress: Float(tmpProgress), playProgress: nil)
    }
}
```